# Trying to do some simple calculations to display on web site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, calculated-field

I am hoping someone can help me out - I am a Javascript novice for sure.  I primarily focus on front-end web site development but a client has asked me if we can display some "cost" options online based on user input.  I was able to succeed in the first pass but once I had to calculate based on a select value things stop working.

Here is my first pass which works for my client and calculates correctly since there is only one unit:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calcform() { 
    with (document.form1)
        { result.value = +number1.value * .75+ +number3.value} /*Calculates Option 1 One Year     Costs.*/
        { result2.value = +number1.value * .75+ +number3.value + +number3.value} /*Calculates     Option 1 Two Years.*/
        { result3.value = +number1.value * .75}/*Calculates Option 1 Leasing Fees.*/
        { result4.value = +number1.value * .08}/*Calculates Option 2 Leasing Fees.*/
        { result5.value = +number1.value * .08 *12 +500}/*Calculates Option 2 One Year Costs.*/
        { result6.value = +number1.value * .08 *24 +500}/*Calculates Option 2 Two Years.*/
    } 
</script> 
<table>
    <form name="form1" action=""> 
        <tr>
            <h5>Prospective Owners Cost Calculator:</h5><br/>
            <h4>Enter Your Anticipated Monthly Rent Here:<br/>
                <input type="text" id="number1" value="" size="20" />
            </h4><br/> 
            <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calcform()" />
            <input type="reset" id="reset" value=" Clear "/>
        </tr><br/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>
                    <strong>Option 1</strong>
                </h4><br/>
                <h4>Leasing Fee (75% of one month's rent):<br /> 
                    <input type="text" id="result3" value="" size="40" />
                </h4><br/>
                <h4>Monthly Management Fee (Fixed $79 x 12 months):<br />
                    <input type="text" id="number3" value="948" size="40" />
                </h4><br/> 
                <h4>Total First Year:<br /> 
                    <input type="text" id="result" value="" size="40" />
                </h4><br/> 
                <h4>Total After 2 Years (assuming lease renewal):<br />
                    <input type="text" id="result2" value="" size="40" />
                </h4><br/>
            </td>
            <br/><br/>
            <td>
                <br><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4>
                    <strong>Option 2</strong>
                </h4><br/>
                <h4>Leasing Fee ($500 fixed):<br />
                    <input type="text" id="number5" value="500" size="40" />
                </h4><br/>
                <h4>Monthly Management Fee (8% of Gross Rents):<br />
                    <input type="text" id="result4" value="" size="40" />
                </h4><br/>
                <h4>Total First Year:<br />
                    <input type="text" id="result5" value="" size="40" />
                </h4><br/>
                <h4>Total After 2 Years (assuming lease renewal):<br />
                    <input type="text" id="result6" value="" size="40" />
                </h4><br/>
            </td> 
        </form>
    </table>
```

I'm trying to add a second form which would go on a different HTML page that would drive additional calculations using a select drop down so a user can indicate number of units, which would drive different calculations.  Told you - I'm a novice!  Greatly appreciate the assistance!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calcform() 
{ 
with (document.form1) 

{ result1.value = +number1.value * .75}/*Calculates Option 1 Leasing Fees.*/
{ result2.value = +number3.value * +number2.value}/*Calculates Option 1 Mgmt Fees all     units.*/

} 
</script> 
<table><form name="form1" action=""> 
<tr><h5>Prospective Owners Cost Calculator:</h5><br/>

<h4>Enter Your Anticipated Monthly Rent Here (Total for all units):<br/>
<input type="text" id="number1" value="" size="20" /></h4><br/>

<h4>Enter the number of units (from 2-6)<br/>
<input type="number" name="number2" value="2" min="2" max="6"/></h4><br/> 

<input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" 
onclick="calcform()" /><input type="reset" id="reset" value=" Clear "/></tr>

<br/><tr><td><h4><strong>Option 1</strong></h4><br/>

<h4>Leasing Fee (75% of one month's rent):<br /> 
<input type="text" id="result1" value="" size="40" /></h4><br/> 

<h4>Monthly Management Fee per unit (Fixed[enter link description here][1] $69 x 12 months):<br /> 
<input type="text" id="number3" value="828" size="40" /></h4><br/> 

<h4>Monthly Management Fee all units:<br /> 
<input type="text" id="result2" value="" size="40" /></h4><br/>
</form> </table>
```

You can see this at dev1.beastlyweb.com.  I've also uploaded the Excel spreadsheet there that contains the calculations the client wants replicated online.

Comment: I can't see the `<select>` dropdown which you said causes errors in your markup? Please include it, and also post the exception message you get (or an exact error description)

Comment: If you're using both forms on the same page, you will need to change the form name and the function name.

Comment: On a side note, you have some pretty significant HTML issues that might or might not impact functionality in certain browsers, depending on how they choose to "fix" them for you: `<tr>` tags with no `<td>` tags in them, `<br \>` tags in `<table>` tags, but outside of `<tr>` and `<td>` sections, missing end tags for `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, etc.  I **highly** recommend that you run your HTML code through the W3C Validator here: http://validator.w3.org/ and fix those issues so that you are working with stable HTML code.

Comment: Thanks.  I mis-spoke - instead of select value it's actually an input type of number with a min of 2 and max of 6.  Also, I am intending these to be two separate forms on two separate pages.  Thanks Bergi!

Comment: Thanks Talemyn!  I'll give the validator a try. I use HTML site builders and customize CSS, so my raw HTML is very weak!  :)

Comment: This was great - I used the tidy clean up and got rid of a lot of issues that were preventing this from calculating in IE.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the calculation is failing because you put `name="number2"` in the input for "Enter the number of units (from 2-6)", instead of `id="number2"`.  You are calling the field by it's `id` in your calculation (`+number2.value`).

Comment: On another side note, keep up the good work . . . you've used a bunch of JavaScript that you rarely see used, which indicates to me that you are researching and doing a lot of trial and error, but without a lot of guidance.  Keep at it and keep asking questions . . . it will get easier.   :)

Comment: Thanks!  You are right on - doing a ton of research and trying stuff - which is a fun way to learn ;)

Comment: That's the way that I did/do it too . . . in fact, I've been doing that way for almost 20 years now, and still learning new stuff every day.   :)

Comment: I also noticed that the input type of "number" doesnt work in any browser except Chrome.  Kind of a bummer since I wanted to use the min and max values.  Any thoughts?  `<h4>Enter the number of units (from 2-6)<br>
<input type="number" id="number2" value="2" min="2" max="6"></h4>` [link](http://dev1.beastlyweb.com)